# Custom Cable Prototype and Manufacture

Tags: connector, cables

I am building an electronic device that has a cable attached to it. I am able to design and order a PCB. I am able to get the PCB assembled with parts. I believe I have enough information to order a prototype case by 3d printing.  What I am not able to do is find a way to get the cable prototyped or manufactured.

Do you know how one would go about getting a custom cable that will be soldered to a PCB on one end? Or maybe it will have a special internal connector on the PCB end. Either way I have not been able to find any information on getting this done.  I don't know if I am using the correct search terms but so far I can only find people wiling to build "pretty" customer cables for keyboards and similar items.  I would like one end to be USB type-c and the other will be permanently attached to my PCB.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would highly advise you stick to using professionally made non custom cables unless you're talkin quantities of thousands.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that is it USB-C is what makes it specialized. If you're not opposed to an internal connector, why not fit a USB-C socket on your board to allow for cheaper USB-C to USB-C cables?

Getting past that, you're after a cabling loom manufacturer. However, to make good USB-C cables it gets much harder than one that crimps and plugs looms for you. Your best starting point may actually be with your PCB / Assembly vendor, as they will have had to handle similar things, with most having the option of basically designing your product from scratch.

If you want a lead on a more local to you option, giving hints of what country you're from will help narrow it down.

Equally, contacting those companies that make USB cables, not the resellers. The resellers usually don't like giving away who their suppliers are.

Comment: How many of these are you making????    Sounds like a single prototype.  If that's the case, wouldn't it be easier to just buy a USB cable and cut the end off???      Check out MOUSER and DIGIKEY.  They have a wide variety of 'semi-custom' pre-fabricated cables.

Comment: I have a hand made cable from parts on digikey. But i need a path going forward. I need a cable mounting strategy to connect it to the pcb. I also need a way to get someone other than me to build the prototypes. I can get the pcb built and the parts assembled for a fee but i have no way to get a cable built.